# Yii model->findAll(), how to add relational table columns?

Tags: php, sql-order-by, foreign-key-relationship, yii

I have two models.  They are DisnotificationUpdate and DisNotification.
DisnotificationUpdate relations are as below.

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Login', 'userid'),
            'notifi' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Disnotification', 'notifi_id'),

        );
    }
```

It's attributes are as following.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'notifi_id' => 'Notifi',
            'view' => 'View',
            'userid' => 'Userid',
        );
    }
```

Disnotification model has following attributes.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'notification' => 'Notification',
            'owner' => 'Owner',
            'workspace_id' => 'Workspace',
            'postID' => 'Post',
            'pDate' => 'P Date',
        );
    }
```

I want to select values from DisnotificationUpdate and order by  values using 'pDate' in DisNotification.
I tried as following.

```
 $dataProvider=DisnotificationUpdate::model()->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'userid=:userid',
        'order' => 'notifi.pDate ASC',
        'limit'=>10,
        'params' => array(':userid' => $myid)
    ));
```

But it is giving an error saying, "Unknown column 'notifi.pDate' in 'order clause'". What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to eager load related model

```
$dataProvider=DisnotificationUpdate::model()->findAll(array(
    'with' => array('notifi'),
    'condition' => 'userid=:userid',
    'order' => 'notifi.pDate ASC',
    'limit'=>10,
    'params' => array(':userid' => $myid)
));
```